# Error with accessing data from grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm getting a *'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row'* error in my code and I'm unsure how to solve it. I tried changing EventArgs to GridViewEventargs but that causes problems with the button used to add data to the database.

Here's the code from my .cs file:

```
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgileDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;

    //set-up connection object called 'myConnection'
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    //myConnection.ConnectionString is now set to connectionString.

    // open database communication
    myConnection.Open();
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    string IDdata = Session["userID"].ToString();
    string OwnerData = txtprojectOwner.Text;
    string MasterData = txtScrumMaster.Text;
    string ManagerData = txtprojectManager.Text;
    TextBox TextBoxfname = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextboxID");
    String fname = TextBoxfname.Text;
    string query = "INSERT INTO [ProjectTeam](userID, projectMan, projectOwner, scrumMaster,developer) VALUES (@UserID,@Mas, @Man, @Own, @Mas,@Del)";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

    //create a parameterised object
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mas", MasterData);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Own", OwnerData);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mas", ManagerData);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dev", TextBoxfname);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", IDdata);
}
```

And here's the Asp.NET code for my grid view.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Widthu="284px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="Make sure you use correct names and or email!" ForeColor="Red" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" Width="814px" DataKeyNames="userID">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />                       
         <Columns> 
             <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="userID" DataTextField="firstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="firstName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="UserProfile.aspx?userID={0}" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="lastName" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" />
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AgileDatabaseConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [userID], [firstName], [lastName], [email] FROM [Users] WHERE (([firstName] LIKE '%' + @firstName + '%') OR ([lastName] LIKE '%' + @lastName + '%') OR ([email] LIKE '%' + @email + '%'))">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="firstName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="lastName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="email" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="userName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

I only need to transfer the userName from the grid view as well as other data coming from dropdown lists that I'm not having issues with elsewhere on the page. Any help resolving this error or a better way of doing it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `(TextBox)(e.Row.FindControl("TextboxID"));` instead?

Comment: @Marc.2377 same error unfortunitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to access a row outside the GridView, you need to specify a row number along with the correct GridView. `EventArgs` only has a `row` definition in a `RowDataBound` event for example. In your snippet it has Button defenitions.

```
TextBox TextBoxfname = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextboxID");
```

This method works if your GridView contains a TextBox in the `TemplateField`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="c"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="getValuesFromGrid" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind with button inside GridView using the `OnRowCommand`

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "getValuesFromGrid")
    {
        int rowNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        TextBox textBox = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        DropDownList dropDownList = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
        Label label = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    }
}
```

Code behind to loop every row in the GridView

```
int rowNumber = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    TextBox textBox = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
    DropDownList dropDownList = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    Label label = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("Label1") as Label;

    rowNumber++;
}
```

Comment: He gridview is populated from a search text box called textbox1 so the control id in the gridview needs to match this, so I'm unsure how I would reference an idvidial row in the gridview

Comment: I doesn't matter where it's populated from. As long as the GridView contains TextBox `TextboxID`, you need to use this method. Or is `TextboxID` outside the GridView?

Comment: The gridview contains TexboxID but every textbox is referenced with the same ID using control ID so trying to reference just one without referencing the textbox used to search is causing the problem

Comment: That is exactly why you need a row number. Post your GridView. And are you invoking `add_Click` from a button that is inside the GridVIew?

Comment: I added the grid view code and no the add_Click button is not inside the Gridview because I'm adding other information to the database at the same time thats not from a gridview its from drop down lists

Comment: There is no TextBox in your GridView. Or a DropDownList you talk about. But I think you want to get values from the GridView. I've added 2 examples.